# Cumulative frequency on normal probability plot

Tags: r, plot, probability

How do I get the cumulative frequency for each unique X value plotted on a normal probability (non linear) y axis. Have used probplot(x) but it doesn't accumulate identical values. My data is a data frame with blood results and. The probplot plots each individual blood result rather than a cumulated frequency for each unique result .

Small data example:

```
V1
7.1
7.2
7.2
7.6
6.8
6.9
6.8
7.4 
7.0
```

I can calculate the cummulated frequency but not plot it with the correct normal probability axis:

```
tabvals <- table(data$V1)

tabvals <- cbind.data.frame(tabvals)

tabvals$frequency <- tabvals$Freq/sum(tabvals$Freq)

tabvals$kummulated <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(tabvals)){
if (i == 1) {
     tabvals$kummulated[i] <- tabvals$frequency[i]
   } else {
       tabvals$kummulated[i] <- tabvals$kummulated[i-1] + tabvals$frequency[i]
     }}

plot(tabvals$Var1, tabvals$kummulated , type="l")
```

The only way to get the right Y axis is this:

```
library(e1071)

probplot(data$V1)
```

But this plots 7.2 and 7.2 as two different points rather than accumulate them.

Comment: It seems like working? ( after changing `plot(tabvals$Var1` to `plot(tabvals$V1` )

Comment: Maybe what you want is `plot.default(x=tabvals$Var1, y=tabvals$kummulated , type="l")`? If not can you explain why the `plot` output is not what you want? Also know that you can just do `tabvals$kummulated <- cumsum(tabvals$frequency)`.

Comment: @bakyaw and @flodel; thx for input.  But the Y axis is still not in the style of a normal probability graph paper (non linear almost logarithmic looking) as you get with probplot() and which is what I need. If I do probplot(tabvals$kummulated) I don't get the right X axis.